# How to Set User-Agents in an HttpRequest (Unit Testing)

Tags: .net, user-agent

I've got a method that takes in an HttpRequest object and performs differently based on what User Agent is set.  I'm trying to unit test it and am having a heck of a time tracking down how to set the User Agent string.  I've tried the raw HttpRequest object and a variety of other objects that eventually yield it to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how to set the user agent string for an HttpRequest object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use a mock HttpRequest object. This will allow you to set various properties so you can test how your webapp responds.

Comment: Mocking a HttpRequest is not possible in my situation (Autofac), since the HttpRequest class is sealed, hence not mockable. Any other solutions available maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UserAgent property on an HttpWebRequest, are you able to use that type instead?